# DirectX Performance Issue maximized window

Tags: windows-7, directx, sharpdx

I develop a test application with directx 11 und fl 10.1.
Everything is working as expected and fine, but when I maximize the window with my graphics in it, the time per frame increases drastically. like 1ms to 40ms.

- NVS 300 graphics card
- Windows 7 32-bit
- Application that draws few sinuses with direct3d, c# via sharpdx
- Windows forms with a control and sharpdx initialized swapchain, programmed to change backbuffer on resize event (would occur without that too though)
- I used a System.Stopwatch to find the issue at the code line:
  mSwapChain.Present(1, PresentFlags.None);
  where the time it needs when maximized increases by a lot suddenly.

any clues?

Comment: Maximizing window increases rendering resolution, isn't it? Maybe it is your drawing code that is to blame?

Comment: It increases the resolution yes. If I test it on my development PC with a HD4400 the frame time stays the same (and there is very little i draw, just a grid and sinus). On my destination machine with the NVS it jumps at a certain resolution. If i resize it manually by dragging, there is a point (not fullscreen) where the time per frame jump up like that. It could be that i do something bad in my code, but this behavior also occurs if I use sharpdx samples from the official git repo. So makes me think it isn't necessarily a issue with my drawing code.

Comment: I can comment out all the drawing commands and just use the Present(1, PresentFlags.None). still the same issue

Comment: What scaling do you specify in the DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 when you create the swapchain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my specific case, switching to windows classic theme with aero disabled solved the issue. Because the frame performance got worse if the windows start button started to lay over the resized window.